# Add new row to excel Table (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel which serves to record the food you ingest for a specific day and meal. I hav a grid in which each line represent a food you ate, how much sugar it has, etc.

Then i've added an save button to save all the data to a table in another sheet.

This is what i have tried

```
    Public Sub addDataToTable(ByVal strTableName As String, ByRef arrData As Variant)
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim iHeader As Integer
    Dim iCount As Integer

    With Worksheets(4).ListObjects(strTableName)
        'find the last row of the list
        lLastRow = Worksheets(4).ListObjects(strTableName).ListRows.Count

        'shift from an extra row if list has header
        If .Sort.Header = xlYes Then
            iHeader = 1
        Else
            iHeader = 0
        End If
    End With

    'Cycle the array to add each value
    For iCount = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        **Worksheets(4).Cells(lLastRow + 1, iCount).Value = arrData(iCount)**
    Next iCount
End Sub
```

but i keep getting the same error on the highlighted line:

```
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't say which version of Excel you are using.  This is written for 2007/2010  (a different apprach is required for Excel 2003 )

You also don't say how you are calling `addDataToTable` and what you are passing into `arrData`.
I'm guessing you are passing a `0` based array.  If this is the case (and the Table starts in Column `A`) then `iCount` will count from `0` and `.Cells(lLastRow + 1, iCount)` will try to reference column `0` which is invalid.

You are also not taking advantage of the `ListObject`.  Your code assumes the `ListObject`1 is located starting at row `1`.  If this is not the case your code will place the data in the wrong row.

Here's an alternative that utilised the `ListObject`

```
Sub MyAdd(ByVal strTableName As String, ByRef arrData As Variant)
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Dim NewRow As ListRow

    ' Based on OP 
    ' Set Tbl = Worksheets(4).ListObjects(strTableName)
    ' Or better, get list on any sheet in workbook
    Set Tbl = Range(strTableName).ListObject
    Set NewRow = Tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

    ' Handle Arrays and Ranges
    If TypeName(arrData) = "Range" Then
        NewRow.Range = arrData.Value
    Else
        NewRow.Range = arrData
    End If
End Sub
```

Can be called in a variety of ways:

```
Sub zx()
    ' Pass a variant array copied from a range
    MyAdd "MyTable", [G1:J1].Value
    ' Pass a range
    MyAdd "MyTable", [G1:J1]
    ' Pass an array
    MyAdd "MyTable", Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot. It's for Office 2010. But this has solved my problem, thanks :)

Comment: where tbl is set in myAdd, referencing a specific worksheet can be somewhat limiting. Alternately the line : Set Tbl=range(strTableName).ListObject      can be used instead, then it works no matter where the table is.

Comment: @RowanC code was based on OP's original code, but your suggestion is better.

Comment: ██  SLOW  ██  Using ListRows.Add is extremely slow!  In a complex sheet, adding 100 rows in this fashion took unacceptable 35 seconds!  (I did turn off events and screen updating).  There must be a better solution.

Comment: @Jonas_Hess I just ran a test on a simple sheet, adding 100 rows took < 0.5s.  So it's not the `AddRows` that's slow, its your "complex" sheet.  Did you try setting Calculation to manual while the code runs?

Comment: Be careful if your target table has filtered or hidden columns.  I've run into some strange results using this macro in Excel 2007.  (e.g., some rows get added fine, but others have the first half of the array copied twice to before and after the hidden columns).

Answer (score 4):

`Tbl.ListRows.Add` doesn't work for me and I believe lot others are facing the same problem. I use the following workaround:

```
    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.count).Range
        For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.count
            If Trim(CStr(lastRow.Cells(1, col).Value)) <> "" Then
                lastRow.Cells(1, col).EntireRow.Insert
                'Cut last row and paste to second last
                lastRow.Cut Destination:=table.ListRows(table.ListRows.count - 1).Range
                Exit For
            End If
        Next col
    End If

    'Populate last row with the form data
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.count).Range
    Range("E7:E10").Copy
    lastRow.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Range("E7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me in my case :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message and after lots of trial and error found out that it was caused by an advanced filter which was set on the ListObject.
After clearing the advanced filter .listrows.add worked fine again.
To clear the filter I use this - no idea how one could clear the filter only for the specific listobject instead of the complete worksheet.

```
Worksheets("mysheet").ShowAllData
```

Comment: `Worksheets("mysheet").ListObjects("tableName").AutoFilter.ShowAllData`

Answer (score 1):

I actually just found that if you want to add multiple rows below the selection in your table 
`Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True` works really well. I just duplicated the code five times to add five rows to my table

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before and i fixed it by creating the same table in a new sheet and deleting all the name ranges associated to the table, i believe whene you're using listobjects you're not alowed to have name ranges contained within your table hope that helps thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue today (Excel crashes on adding rows using `.ListRows.Add`).
After reading this post and checking my table, I realized the calculations of the formula's in some of the cells in the row depend on a value in other cells.
In my case of cells in a higher column AND even cells with a formula!

The solution was to fill the new added row from back to front, so calculations would not go wrong.

Excel normally can deal with formula's in different cells, but it seems adding a row in a table kicks of a recalculation in order of the columns (A,B,C,etc..).

Hope this helps clearing issues with `.ListRows.Add`

Answer (score -1):

As using `ListRow.Add` can be a huge bottle neck, we should only use it if it can’t be avoided.
If performance is important to you, use this function here to resize the table, which is quite faster than adding rows the recommended way.

Be aware that this will **overwrite data** below your table if there is any!

This function is based on the accepted answer of  *Chris Neilsen*

```
Public Sub AddRowToTable(ByRef tableName As String, ByRef data As Variant)
    Dim tableLO As ListObject
    Dim tableRange As Range
    Dim newRow As Range

    Set tableLO = Range(tableName).ListObject
    tableLO.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    If (tableLO.ListRows.Count = 0) Then
        Set newRow = tableLO.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True).Range
    Else
        Set tableRange = tableLO.Range
        tableLO.Resize tableRange.Resize(tableRange.Rows.Count + 1, tableRange.Columns.Count)
        Set newRow = tableLO.ListRows(tableLO.ListRows.Count).Range
    End If

    If TypeName(data) = "Range" Then
        newRow = data.Value
    Else
        newRow = data
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting to note, the more rows the table has the slower this runs.  there comes a point where `ListRows.Add` is faster

Answer (score -2):

Just delete the table and create a new table with a different name. Also Don't delete entire row for that table. It seems when entire row containing table row is delete it damages the DataBodyRange is damaged