# Copy filled rows from table to another

Tags: vba, excel, format, copy

I am new to VBA and I'm trying to write a Macro in Excel that copies a table to another table and then deletes lines where a cell is equal to the value "0".

I have a table as follows:

[image]

I want the table to look like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Let me see if I got it: you need to copy data from table1, that is not equal to 0, and paste it in table2? Do you need to delete any rows? In your second image, there are 0's left at third line, why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299898/vba-copy-and-paste-table-row-to-another-table

Comment: it's an error. it is supposed to delete all "0" values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will copy data from a table in Sheet1 to Sheet2 where the second column is not 0 - using the table's Autofilter.

I had to add a 1 second `application.wait` to allow the filter to be applied before copying. This might need increasing depending on table size. Perhaps someone else could help with a more robust method of waiting for the filter to apply..?

```
Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
Dim destination_sheet As Worksheet

Set source_sheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set destination_sheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With source_sheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>0"
        Application.Wait 1
        .Copy Destination:=destination_sheet.Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=2
    End With
```

It's worth mentioning that the output to Sheet2 is not in a *true* table form. However, it shouldn't be tricky to record a macro where you convert it to a table to gain that piece of code too.