# Moving Rows from One Table to Another (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to automate somewhat of a cut and paste function within my workbook to transfer returned loan details from an outstanding loans sheet onto a 'LoansHistory' sheet. I found this code online and have been trying to modify it to add the row contents to an existing table based on the presence of a date (or any text, currently) in a corresponding 'column K' Cell.

Essentially, being brand new at coding in general, I am having extreme difficulty modifying the below code to look for and paste rows into an existing table using `ListObjects.ListRows` instead of the next empty row (as it currently does).

I understand there are a few other posts where others have addressed this, but as my knowledge of VBA is very limited, I am still struggling to apply the appropriate changes.

I am constantly getting error codes such as "Sub Script Out of Range" or "Object does not support this function" when attempting to use `ListObjects.ListRows` functions.

Any help at all would be extremely appreciated.

```
Sub Cheezy()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long

   i = Worksheets("Loans").UsedRange.Rows.count
   J = Worksheets("LoansHistory").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("LoansHistory").ListObjects("History")) = 0 Then J = 0
       End If
  Set xRg = Worksheets("Loans").Range("K4:K" & i)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For K = 1 To xRg.count
       If Len(xRg(K).Value) > 0 Then
          xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("LoansHistory").Range("A" & (J + 1))
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If Len(xRg(K).Value) > 0 Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
         End If
      Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting rows, work from the bottom up.  And it's a good rule to follow to never modify the counter variable inside of a `For` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - appreciated. The error seems to be with my incorrectly modified `If Not` statement.

Comment: Is it either a date or empty?  If so it's easiest to test for `If Len(xRg(K).Value) > 0 Then`

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks! Would you by any chance know how to fix the copy location from cell 600 odd to the top of the table? And if it can be automated by the occurrence as opposed to manually having to run the macro each time? Apologies, I am extremely new at coding.

Comment: You're using UsedRange which is sensitive to formatting I think  - you might be better off using something like `J = Worksheets("LoansHistory").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1` as long as there will always be content in ColA for any copied rows.

Comment: Cool, that does work better, but I have a table formatted in this sheet however, and am now trying to alter the code to copy it into the a new row in said table - is this easily done?

Comment: If you have the destination sheet formatted as a table then you can use the methods available for listobjects to add the new row - eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299898/vba-copy-and-paste-table-row-to-another-table

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!

Comment: @TimWilliams I keep getting run time error 438 (object does not support this property or method) when I try to use `listobject.listrows.add` for my table. Any common causes of this?

Comment: Maybe update your post to add your revised code - difficult to say what the problem is without that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't really been able to revise the code much at all - I am getting quite confused as to how to incorporate listobjects correctly. I've been reading posts all day, still no clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this you could fairly easily see where it is crashing by putting a breakpoint in the code and stepping through it.

Either click on the left bar next to the code area until the code line turns red, or just add a `Stop` command into your code.

Also, comment out the two `Application.ScreenUpdating =` commands for now. While you are debugging these will only hinder you. If the error occurs in between them then you will struggle to get your screen updating back on. You can run the latter one in the debug window (Ctrl+G) to turn it back on. For now, just leave the screen updating on.

Once you've hit a breakpoint you can press F8 to continue through the code one command at a time until you find the line which errors. Experiment with it, it will really help when you hit a stumbling block such as this.

I don't like this part of the code at a glance `.Range("A" & J + 1)` though, try putting the J+1 in an extra set of brackets. `.Range("A" & (J + 1))`.

Comment: Thanks! The error seems to be within the `If Not`. Tim above assisted on how to fix!