# Add row to table then add formulas to multiple columns in row

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim StrFormula1, StrFormula2 As String
Dim NewRow As ListRow
StrFormula1 = "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & newName & "'!A1"",newName & ""!A1)"
StrFormula2 = "=" & newName & "!C9"

Set Tbl = Range("tblProjects").ListObject
Set NewRow = Tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
NewRow.Range = Array(StrFormula1, StrFormula2)
```

For the last line I keep getting an error. This is based on the question [Add new row to excel Table (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297738/add-new-row-to-excel-table-vba)

I've tried a few other options for the last line but none of them work.  I don't know if it's because they're formulas or what.  In another spreadsheet I have I'm using `Range(ResultCol & UCRow).Formula = StrFormula` but in that case the range is not based on a table but static cell values.

So, how can I apply a couple formulas to `NewRow`?

Comment: did you create the table with VBA or does it already exist?. Existing tables would have their formulas already set up. New rows will inherit the existing formulas. Are you trying to add new formulas to the table?

Comment: It does already exist.  Background: This table is on a "dashboard" sheet.  This code is part of a function that creates a new worksheet/tab and then adds some things to an "index" of sorts.  That being the case, the formula for the table can't really be set ahead of time because the tab names could be different.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: the reason the code fails is that `StrFormula1` is an invalid formula. Correct that and the wode works.  Eg if `newName` had the value `Sheet1` then `StrFormula1` = `=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!A1",newName & "!A1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

corrected formula:

```
StrFormula1 = "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & newName & "'!A1""," & newName & "!A1)"
```

You may also want to wrap newName in a single quote in the second reference, in case the newName contains a space.

```
StrFormula1 = "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & newName & "'!A1"",'" & newName & "'!A1)"
```

Comment: I corrected my post a few minutes ago. I get no message. File open dialog  appears when a sheet name does not exist and Excel tries to be helpful and wants you to open the file with the sheet it can't find. Check the sheet name. Use the lower of the two formulas, which will accommodate spaces in sheet names.

Comment: Yeah sorry that went away.  I guess it was trying to save it.  Very strange.  Anyway, column1 StrFormula1 seems to be working consistently.  However, when I write a new value for Formula2 it updates all the previous rows.  I'll update with screenshots.

Comment: The nature of a table is that a formula applies to the whole column. If you overwrite an existing formula that applies to the whole column, the new formula will now be the column formula. To break that behaviour, enter a constant into one cell of the column. Now change the formula in another cell of the column. Change the first cell back to its original formula. Now the column no longer has just one formula and you can add more formulas without affecting the whole column.

Comment: What do you mean? I just showed you the workaround you need.

Comment: Follow up, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189246/unique-formulas-in-table-managed-by-code