# Copy row a certain amount of times

Tags: excel

I have a sheet where I have a table of like 30 rows, this is set in another cell. is there a way that it auto updates the table that if I change the 30 into 31 that it duplicates the last line and adds it beneath the last row of the table?
I looked this up on google and the only thing I could find was a macro that inserts another row, but I don't know how I can get it to work that it updates the formulas in the excel sheet[image]

[image]

Comment: Whoever upvoted this care to explain how this question shows research effort?

Comment: I edited it with the research I did. It was all I could find

Comment: I wasn't asking you. And the upvote happened before your edit. Edit: not that your edit is worth anything XD

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297738/add-new-row-to-excel-table-vba

Comment: If it is a table then the formula should update and populate with the addition of the new row.

Comment: Also, kindly read through [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ScottCraner okay thanks for that information

Comment: @BruceWayne I'll read through it, thanks.