# Is there an excel VBA code to expand or add rows to tables when it is full?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all I am looking for a dynamic solution that adds rows to my tables on a sheet when it is almost full.

I am using this (Code below) where range B2 and E2 keep track of the last cell in each table.
I am going to work with script that generates new tables dynamically and this solution wont work. Can someone please help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells, KeyCells2, KeyCells3 As Range

Dim x, i, a, b As Integer

i = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
x = i - 1
a = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").Value
b = a - 1

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
'Set KeyCells = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2)
Set KeyCells = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2)
Set KeyCells2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(b, 2)
Set KeyCells3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:L28")

'MsgBox "Cell " & KeyCells.Address

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
Is Nothing Then
'MsgBox "trigger 1"
' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
' changed.
' Place your code here.
Call Module1.AddRows
MsgBox Target.Value & " has been added."


ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells2, Range(Target.Address)) _
Is Nothing Then
'MsgBox "trigger 2"
' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
' changed.

' Place your code here.
Call Module2.AddRows2


ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells3, Range(Target.Address)) _
Is Nothing Then
'MsgBox "trigger 2"
' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
' changed.

' Place your code here.
MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed to " & Target.Value



End If

End Sub
```

The add rows module is Below

```
Sub AddRows()
Dim i, x, a, b As Integer
Dim lastRow, checkRow As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject



i = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
a = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").Value
x = i - 1
b = a - 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3")

Set lastRow = ws.Cells(i, 2)
Set checkRow = ws.Cells(x, 2)


If Not IsEmpty(checkRow.Value) Then

tbl.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
tbl.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
tbl.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
tbl.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
tbl.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

i = i + 5
x = i - 1

a = a + 5
b = a - 1
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = i
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("c2").Value = x

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").Value = a
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F2").Value = b

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.4490566038, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
MsgBox x
Exit Sub

Else

End If

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Range(Target.Address)` is the same as `Target`.

Comment: Thanks JMP. will take note of that.

Comment: `ListRows.Add` is what you need. You can search SO for specific questions. To start you off, check out the answer to this SO question [Add new row to excel Table (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297738/add-new-row-to-excel-table-vba)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got a work around and streamlined my code a lot, Here it is if anyone is interested:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim hdr_row As Long, last_row As Long, lastdata_row As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject

'Loop through each sheet and table in the workbook
For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects

'Do something to all the tables...


If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.Range) Is Nothing Then
With tbl
'the header row
hdr_row = .HeaderRowRange.Cells(1).Row
'last row of table
last_row = .ListRows.Count + hdr_row
'last row with data in listcolumn(1) <-- first table column
lastdata_row = .DataBodyRange.Cells(.ListRows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'number of existing blank rows
x = last_row - lastdata_row
'if less than 3 blanks add another 5
If x < 3 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
For i = 1 To 5
.ListRows.Add
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End With
End If

Next tbl
End Sub
```