# Loop through each chart in a work sheet and add a row for each variable using vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I would like to loop through each chart in a worksheet and modify the data range by adding one more observation

Example:
I have a combined graph that contains two line charts.
First line chart Data range : J43:J144

Second line chart Data range : AE43:AE144

I would like it to become

First line chart Data range : J43:J145

Second line chart Data range : AE43:AE145

This should apply to each chart even it has more than one series

I know how to loop through each graph however I don't know how to add one row to the data range

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()


       Dim sht As Worksheet
       Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
       Dim cht As ChartObject
  
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Application.EnableEvents = False

       Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

       For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 
       For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects

        cht.Activate    

        'Add one column in the data range'  
     
        Next cht
        Next sht

        CurrentSheet.Activate
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be able to record a macro to do this for you. Try it and see how you get along.

Comment: thank you for your response, I already did that it.                                              
  Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=xxx!$J$43:$J$145"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=xxx!$AE$43:$AE$145"
End Sub.                                                              it changes the number that's it I want a function to add a +1 if you get what I mean

Comment: so, before the loop....count = 1
then, after you enter the loop....count = count + 1

Comment: I am so sorry I am still new to VBA could you please help me more on what to write exactly thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but maybe you need to do it like this.

```
Sub CounterIncrement()

Dim c As Integer

c = 0

Do
c = c + 1
Debug.Print c
Loop Until c = 10

End Sub
```

This will print  1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10 in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I don't see how that can help me

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really trying to do. Don't you want to insert a row in a range, or add a row to a table?

https://excelchamps.com/vba/insert-row/

...or...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297738/add-new-row-to-excel-table-vba

Comment: I want to tell excel to just add one observation in the chart for each variable without changing anything like the example I cited above

Comment: I'm not sure what this means: 'Add one column in the data range'. Can you update your original post with a before and after screen shot? What do you have now and what do you want to see after the code runs?